# Subconscious vs Unconscious in The Big Bang Theory Series

Tags: meaning, grammar

The Big Bang Theory season 11, episode 15:

Leonard: "I didn't intend to write about Penny ... maybe ***subconsciously*** I did."

Leonard's mother: "I believe you mean ***unconsciously*** dear."

I have read here on SE and other sites that subconscious is the proper word to use and unconscious means you're passed out and not in your senses.

Have I been mistaken all this time?

Comment: Isn't Leonard's mother being sardonic here?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I don't know, perhaps she is. English is my third language so sometimes these nuanced undertones escapes me.

Comment: She is being sarcastic. Unconsciously literally means "with no thinking", she doesn't have a high opinion of Leonard's thinking

Answer (score 2):

Leonard's mother is a therapist, thereby probably  conversant with psychoanalysis, in which the technical term used by Freud is "the unconscious" as in mind. There are, however, three levels of mind in Freud: [three levels](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/works-conscious-subconscious-unconscious-mind-dr-c-demarco-)

So, her sarcasm is based on her own professional jargon. And, when  you have a lapse of the tongue or bungled act, this speech and action respectively are said to be due to the unconscious, the deepest level and not just under the surface (subconscious). Freud would not locate a lapse at the level of a subconscious. It would be said to emanate from the unconscious.

Slips of the tongue (lapsus linguae) are briefly explained here: [lapses](http://lapse). These are also known as: Freudian slips, in English.

The Big Bang Theory contains surprisingly tricky jokes. This  is one of them.

[unconscious](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unconscious_mind)

Comment: I think the Freudian point is the correct interpretation of this. Although, I don't think she was being sarcastic because in the next line Leonard says, "It would be nice if you didn't correct me all the time." So either she was correct or he didn't know the difference between subconscious and unconscious either.

Comment: @zindarod She was correcting  him and being sarcastic in doing so. It was the last or next-to-last episode, and I saw it and you can tell from  her tone of voice.

Comment: I am confused. Doesn't sarcasm mean the opposite of what one's saying? So if she was being sarcastic then unconsciously is not the correct choice, subconsciously is.

Comment: @zindarod No, not necessarily. Sarcasm is complicated but your statement about it is not accurate and applies binary logic to the semantic situation.